# How to Evict less frequently used cache region periodicly?

Tags: java, hibernate, ehcache

According to this 
[Ehcache_Configuration_Guide.pdf](http://ehcache.org/generated/2.9.0/pdf/Ehcache_Configuration_Guide.pdf)

> How Configuration Affects Element Flushing and Eviction
>   The following example shows a cache with certain expiration seings:
>       `<cache name="myCache"`
>        `eternal="false" timeToIdleSeconds="3600"`
>        `timeToLiveSeconds="0" memoryStoreEvictionPolicy="LFU">`
>       `</cache>`
>   Note the following about the myCache configuration:
>   If a client accesses an entry in myCache that has been idle for more than an hour timeToIdleSeconds), that element is evicted.
>   If an entry expires but is not accessed, and no resource constraints force eviction, then the expired entry remains in place until a periodic evictor removes it.

I didn't find any exemple of how to configure the eviction periodicly,

is it configurable?
or it must be hard-coded for hibernate?

According to this page [ExpiryTaskExtension.java](https://github.com/OpenGamma/OG-Platform/blob/9e6e757c3ff487f01b6ccc63cffb1f4f21b03f59/projects/OG-Util/src/main/java/com/opengamma/util/ehcache/ExpiryTaskExtension.java)
There is no default schedular for time eviction in ehCache

Comment: does [this](http://ankursinghal86.blogspot.in/2014/07/how-hibernate-second-level-cache-works.html) help you

Comment: i think i should dig this http://docs-static.opengamma.com/1.0.0/java/javadocs/com/opengamma/util/ehcache/ExpiryTaskExtension.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
import java.util.Timer;
import java.util.TimerTask;
import net.sf.ehcache.CacheManager;

public class EhCacheExpiryTask {
    class ExpiryTask extends TimerTask{
        @Override
        public void run() {
            for (CacheManager manager : CacheManager.ALL_CACHE_MANAGERS) {
                for (String name : manager.getCacheNames()) {
                    //manager.getCache(name).getCacheConfiguration().setStatistics(true);
                    manager.getCache(name).evictExpiredElements();                 
                } 
            }        
        }
    }
    private Timer timer;
    private long period;
    private ExpiryTask expiryTask;
    public EhCacheExpiryTask(long period){
        this.period = period;
        this.timer = new Timer();
    } 
    public void stop(){
        timer.cancel();
    }
    public void start(){
        expiryTask = new ExpiryTask();      
        timer.schedule(expiryTask, 10000, period);
    }
}
```